# Induced drag - inverse proportion between induced drag and parasitic drag

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics

I recently learned that the slower an aircraft is traveling, the higher the induced drag and the lower the parasitic drag. The parasitic drag is lower because the particles have less force against the aircraft (all types of parasite drag: form, skinfriction, interference, and ram). However, why is induced drag higher?

From what I understand, I thought that it would be low as well, because if the aircraft is moving slower that would mean that the air pressure would be less on the bottom of the planform, meaning the vortex created at the tip of the wing would be smaller (smaller difference between pressures) thus having less induced drag.

Can someone help explain to me why it is inversely proportional as such?